# Finding the sum of values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The number $2001$  can be written in the form of $x^2-y^2$ when $x,y$ are positive integers  in four different ways ,then how to find the the sum of $x$ values

Comment: Is there an argument why you don't brute force it ?

Comment: Self work, ideas, effort...?

Comment: How can there be 4 pairs ? I think there are only 2

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Anybody brute-forcing this (i.e. not seeing the factorization trick) would be doomed to try arbitrarily large $x,y$.

Comment: @Amr $2^3/2=4$.

Comment: @Haegen von Eitzen Why? Its either x+y=2001,x-y=1     or x+y=667,x-y=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ with $0<x-y<x+y$ and $2001$ has which property?

---

*Complete "theory" of this:*

For $n\in \mathbb N$, let $$f(n)=\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathbb N^2,\atop x^2-y^2=n} x$$
be the result we are looking for.

Given $n\in\mathbb N$, any solution to $x^2-y^2=n$ with $x,y\in\mathbb N$ determines a divisor $d=x-y$ of $n$ because $n=x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$. We have $d>0$ because $x-y=\frac n{x+y}>0$ and $d<\sqrt n$ because $x+y>x-y$.

On the other hand, if $n$ is odd, then any positive divisor $d$ of $n$ with $d^2<n$ gives rise to a solution $x-y=d, x+y=\frac nd$, i.e. $x=\frac{d+\frac nd}2$, $y=\frac{\frac nd-d}2$ (note that $\frac nd$ is also odd, hence the numerators are even). 
If $n$ is even but not a multiple of $4$, then $d$ and $\frac nd$ in the expressions above always have  different parity, hence there is no solution. If $n$ is a multiple of $4$, then $d$ and $\frac nd$ must both be chosen even, that is $d$ is a divisor of $\frac n4$.
In summary this means

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}\tfrac12\sigma(n)&\text{if }n\text{ odd and not a perfect square},\\
\tfrac12(\sigma(n)-\sqrt n)&\text{if }n\text{ odd and perfect square},\\
0&\text{if }n\equiv 2\pmod 4,\\
\tfrac12\sigma(\tfrac n4)&\text{if }4|n\text{ and $n$ not a perfect square},\\
\tfrac12\sigma(\tfrac n4)-\frac14\sqrt n&\text{if }n\text{ is an even perfect square}.\end{cases} $$
Here, $\sigma(n)$ denotes the sum of all (positive) divisors of $n$.
It is well-known that
$$\sigma(n)=\prod_{p|n,\atop p\text{ prime}}\frac{p^{k_p+1}-1}{p-1}\qquad\text{if }n=\prod_{p|n,\atop p\text{ prime}}p^{k_p} . $$

Now find the prime factorization of $n=2001$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ and the prime factorization of $2001$ to explicitly find the solutions $(x,y)$.

Comment: It is mentioned that $x$ is a positive integer

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer rushed too much, *even* if it is wrong. Give people a little more slack!

Comment: Amr: Thanks. I changed my answer to be of more value, hopefully.

Comment: DonAntonio: Admittedly, I had the same feeling. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @azimut You are welcome. your idea was nice

Comment: @DonAntonio I agree with you ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$2001=3\cdot667=(x-y)(x+y)\Longrightarrow\begin{cases}x-y=3\\x+y=667\end{cases}$$

...or the other way around and minus signs....

Comment: Not or the other way round and not minus signs. But we have different options to write $2001=a\cdot b$.

Comment: Yes the other way around and yes the minus signs: will you **please** let the OP sort out his/her options alone?! If he wants to rule out something *later* then he will.

Comment: No reason to get worried - I merely wanted to point out that the OP required $x,y$ to be positive integers, hence minus signs are ruled out, as is letting $x-y$ be the bigger factor.

Comment: Let him deduce his stuff alone! I also did *not* include in the hints the rather obvious $\,2001=1\cdot 2001\,$...but if you don't give the OP even 10 minutes to swallow the hint then it doesn't serve him very good, does it?

Comment: Agreed. But then it would maybe have been better to merely write "For example". Adding "or red herring" but silently dropping the *really* relevant "or" gave me the impression of intended completeness, esp. as swapping order and signs could account for a count of four solutions as requested. Sorry again, and for me eod - before we get expelled from here into chat :)